How to update the .NET SDK version in my Azure App Service?
I'm most certainly missing some basic understanding here,
but I think I need to update the .NET version in my Azure App Service.
So, the currently installed version is 8.0.205:

Now, my actual web app is using .NET 8.0.6, like in
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="8.0.6" />.
So I'm expecting errors when using 8.0.6 features.
With that, how can I tell the Azure App Service to update its .NET version from 8.0.205 to 8.0.6?

Check the extension in the Azure App Service.

8.0.205 is a newer version than 8.0.6, since 205 > 6. Check out semantic versioning: https://semver.org/ . 8.0.6 is also not the version of .NET it is using, but rather the version of the nuget package. Packages (typically?) only target major versions.

You can also check it in the KUDU

Are you sure, .NET SDK 8.0.6 exists ?May be you are confused with Runtime version.Please cross check once.

Check this Doc for the available SDK versions.


how can I tell the Azure App Service to update its .NET version from 8.0.205 to 8.0.6?

You can check the available .NET SDK Version in this MSDoc.

I don't see any SDK with version 8.0.6.The version which you are referring is related to ASP.NET Core Runtime.

You can install the .NET SDK Version from PowerShell in KUDU Console.


I have taken references from this MSDoc.

First you need to add the DOTNET_ROOT and DOTNET_HOST_PATH Environment Variables in the App Settings.

DOTNET_ROOT = C:\Program Files\dotnet
DOTNET_HOST_PATH = dotnet.exe 



Download the dotnet-install.ps1 from dotnet.microsoft.com.

Upload the downloaded dotnet-install.ps1 in the site/wwwroot root folder (simple drag and drop).




Open KUDU Console = > Powershell



Navigate to site/wwwroot directory and run the below commands.

./dotnet-install.ps1 -Channel LTS



You can see the updated SDK version.


